# Transform string column into datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp

I know this question was asked multiple times and I went through the solutions, however I couldn't find a solution to my problem

I do have two time columns, one column is time and one column is date column. What I would like to achieve is to have a merged column, i.e. timestamp column

Column A looks like this

```
0       "3.11.20"
1       "3.11.20"
2       "3.11.20"
3       "3.11.20"
4       "3.11.20"
   
1087    "5.11.20"
1088    "5.11.20"
1089    "5.11.20"
1090    "5.11.20"
1091    "5.11.20"
```

Column B looks like this

```
0       "11:38:48"
1       "11:39:44"
2       "11:41:35"
3       "11:42:31"
4       "11:43:27"
   
1087    "14:51:10"
1088    "14:52:01"
1089    "14:52:53"
1090    "14:53:44"
1091    "14:54:36"
```

My first approach was following, with follwing output

```
df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["colA"]+" "+df["colB"])


Unknown string format: "3.11.20" "11:38:48"
```

So my next approach was to transform each column indiviually to check the error, and got the following error

```
pd.to_datetime(raw_data["colA"],
                     format="%d.%m.%y")

time data '"3.11.20"' does not match format '%d.%m.%y' (match)
```

I am negatively surprised about having so much issues transforming these string columns into datetime format. I would be very grateful for any advice. I assume this might be due to padding zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use format with `""` values with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert wrong values to `NaT` for missing values for datetimes:

```
df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["colA"]+df["colB"], 
                               format='"%d.%m.%y""%H:%M:%S"',
                               errors='coerce')
```

Or remove `"` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["colA"].str.strip('"')+" "+
                               df["colB"].str.strip('"'), 
                               format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S', 
                               errors='coerce')
```

---

```
print (df)
             colA        colB           Timestamp
0.0     "3.11.20"  "11:38:48" 2020-11-03 11:38:48
1.0     "3.11.20"  "11:39:44" 2020-11-03 11:39:44
2.0     "3.11.20"  "11:41:35" 2020-11-03 11:41:35
3.0     "3.11.20"  "11:42:31" 2020-11-03 11:42:31
4.0     "3.11.20"  "11:43:27" 2020-11-03 11:43:27
1087.0  "5.11.20"  "14:51:10" 2020-11-05 14:51:10
1088.0  "5.11.20"  "14:52:01" 2020-11-05 14:52:01
1089.0  "5.11.20"  "14:52:53" 2020-11-05 14:52:53
1090.0  "5.11.20"  "14:53:44" 2020-11-05 14:53:44
1091.0  "5.11.20"  "14:54:36" 2020-11-05 14:54:36
```

Comment: @SMS - Sorry, ithere was wrong `)`, now tested and working well.

Comment: if I apply your second option I get the following error time data '(null) (null)' does not match format '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @SMS - I got it, there are some wrong data, add `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaT` - it is missing value for datetime in pandas. Answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, there was a god damn null value in the data. You saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using read_csv use parse_dates=[['colA', 'colB']] in parameter, and after use your code

```
df["Timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["colA"]+" "+df["colB"])
```

Comment: Also tried it as one of the many attemps. However it's not working

Comment: Try to change the separator to '-' or '/' for date values with value.replace('.', '-') for example

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
print(df)

     ColumnA     ColumnB
0     "3.11.20"  "11:38:48"
1     "3.11.20"  "11:39:44"
2     "3.11.20"  "11:41:35"
3     "3.11.20"  "11:42:31"
4     "3.11.20"  "11:43:27"
1087  "5.11.20"  "14:51:10"
1088  "5.11.20"  "14:52:01"
1089  "5.11.20"  "14:52:53"
1090  "5.11.20"  "14:53:44"
1091  "5.11.20"  "14:54:36"
```

Solution

Strip the `"` and use `.str.cat` to concat. Coerce to datetime using .pd.to_datetime

```
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnA'].str.strip('"').str.cat(df['ColumnB'].str.strip('"'), sep=' '), format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")

      ColumnA     ColumnB           timestamp
0     "3.11.20"  "11:38:48" 2020-11-03 11:38:48
1     "3.11.20"  "11:39:44" 2020-11-03 11:39:44
2     "3.11.20"  "11:41:35" 2020-11-03 11:41:35
3     "3.11.20"  "11:42:31" 2020-11-03 11:42:31
4     "3.11.20"  "11:43:27" 2020-11-03 11:43:27
1087  "5.11.20"  "14:51:10" 2020-11-05 14:51:10
1088  "5.11.20"  "14:52:01" 2020-11-05 14:52:01
1089  "5.11.20"  "14:52:53" 2020-11-05 14:52:53
1090  "5.11.20"  "14:53:44" 2020-11-05 14:53:44
1091  "5.11.20"  "14:54:36" 2020-11-05 14:54:36
```